# JMX attribute naming conventions

Tags: java, naming-conventions, jmx

I've noticed that the convention for JMX MBeans appears to deviate from the standard Java Bean property model in that the names for attributes will traditionally start with a capital letter, i.e. PascalCase.

To explain this a bit more clearly, I'll take an example from the JDK (chopped down a bit for clarity) :

```
public interface MemoryMXBean {
    public int getObjectPendingFinalizationCount();

    public MemoryUsage getHeapMemoryUsage();

    public MemoryUsage getNonHeapMemoryUsage();

    public boolean isVerbose();

    public void setVerbose(boolean value);

}
```

And the Memory MXBean exposed has attributes **V** erbose, **H** eapMemoryUsage etc..
This is also the case for every MBean exposed, and you receive the same behaviour when defining your own MBeans.

Does anyone know the origins of this convention / implementation detail?
I glanced through the JMX spec and only found a passing referencing to case sensitivity of attribute names, with no clear convention mentioned.

Comment: Do the origins really matter? Someone on the spec committee screwed up, and now we're stuck with it.

Comment: Well, it would be nice to know if it was intentional or an oversight.